# Как наложить картинку макета приложения на Preview в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Имеется нарисованный макет в формате PNG, как можно наложить эту картинку на предосмотр активити, чтобы выровнять элементы, и вообще подогнать все под макет? слышал что в разработке под IOS такая штука есть, а в Android Studio как обстоит дело? другого варианта "сверстать".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите картинку в папку drawable.В свойстве background в LinearLayout,RealativeL и.т.д. поставьте эту картинку.Примерно вот так :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background3">
</LinearLayout>
```

Точно также и в другие элементы (ImageButton,ImageView и.т.д).

Comment: была такая мысль но я думал что может что-то более человечное будет)